# .NET Uri convert %3a back to colon

Tags: c#, .net, http, url

I need to use `HttpWebRequest` class to post data. My target uri looks like `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http://www.foo.com`. After Urlencode, it turns to `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com`. But when I use

```
WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com") as HttpWebRequest;
```

It actually send `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http:%2F%2Fwww.foo.com`(it converts `%3A` back to colon), and goes wrong. So how can I send `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com` instead of `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http:%2F%2Fwww.foo.com`?

---

Update:
Example code:

```
const string queryParam = @"http://www.foo.com";
UriBuilder bulider = new UriBuilder
{
    Scheme = "http",
    Host = @"www.foo.com",
    Path = "index.jsp",
    Query = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryParam)
};

Uri uri = bulider.Uri;
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
```

output result:

```
http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?http:%2f%2fwww.foo.com
```

---

Update:

There is different behaviour in different .NET version. In .NET 4.5.2, the output is `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?http:%2f%2fwww.foo.com`, and in .NET 4.0, the output is `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?http://www.foo.com`.

Comment: No repro. Using Fiddler as a proxy, the URI is `http://www.foo.com/index.jsp?value=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com ` Why do you assume that the URI was converted by .NET? It's far more likely that the *server* decodes the *query parametere only*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What version of .NET are you using? I heard this works from 4.5 onwards and that older versions had issues. I could be mistaken, unable to test right now.

Comment: @Equalsk in this case the OP should upgrade. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2. Given that TLS1.2 was added in 4.5.2, the upgrade should be considered mandatory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hehe, in an ideal world where people do ideal things I'd agree. We're still stuck with 3.5 and Core for our external software, but that's a different story ;-)

Comment: In the ideal world, you could remain on 3.5. In the real world, you won't be able to connect to any site or REST service that uses TLS1.2. Banks, airlines, payment gateways etc already require TLS1.2.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos by the way, my .NET project version is 4.5.2

Comment: @YuhengHuang that code has nothing to do with the original question and doesn't produce the same string. The query parameter doesn't have the `value` key. If you test your *original* code with Fiddler you'll see that the URL isn't modified